# Можно ли передать параметр даты к src скрипта?

Tags: javascript

Допустим есть такой скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="theremyjsscript/myjs.js"></script>
```

Как можно к этому src добавить дату, чтобы src принял такой вид: `"http://theremyjsscript/myjs.js?_dc=" + (new Date().getTime())`

Может как-нибудь программно можно это сделать?

Суть затеи в том, чтобы каждый раз запускался скрипт с новым параметром, чтобы запускался новый скрипт, а не скрипт из кэша.

Для этого делают типа: `<script src="myfile.js?version=1.0.0"></script>`, а потом меняют версию и соответственно откроется свежий скрипт, но у меня такой возможности не будет, т.к. у меня не сайт, а приложение, которое устанавливается на смарт тв, а туда приложения выкладываются месяцами...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'http://go.iptvportal.ru/static/portal/standalone.js?_dc=' + (new Date().getTime());    

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Добавьте этот код где-то на странице или в заголовке.

Comment: Работать же не будет...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, почему? :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/w87zgyfv/ - о_О и правда работает. Загвоздка в том, чтобы "создающий" скрипт прилепить в самом конце страницы? Чтобы всё что есть в скрипте-ссылке, сработало уже на загруженном HTML...

Comment: Я делал прямо в head так <script type="text/javascript" src="theremyjsscript/myjs.js?_dc=" + (new Date().getTime())></script>, и среда ругалась на эту запись, но всё запускалось и работало. Мне кажется это аналогично тому, что вы написали, но я не уверен, что этот параметр добавляется к ссылке... Можно ли как-то это проверить? А то я думаю, что просто ссылка открывается без параметра и в итоге там всегда будет один параметр типа null

Comment: @ДмитрийЧубаров в вашем случае никто конкатенацию строк проводить не будет, сам `html` такое не умеет, поэтому не будет работать